# Instruct GYP to add header files in an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, gyp

When using GYP to generate an Xcode project using a fairly basic .gyp file, it adds all the source files but not the .h files.

Is there a way to instruct it to also include all header files that are used in the project? Or would you need to add them manually, after the project is generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add any header files to the `sources` list in the .gyp file.